# Is Window's system restoration useful for getting rid of malware?

Tags: windows, malware, tools

If your computer has been infected with some kind of malware, could a restoration of the system, using the tool provided by windows, help you getting rid of that malware?

We should suppose that it exists a restoration point before the infection, and also that the date of the infection is known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**System restore does not track all system changes.** This is a myth. Most files are not covered by system restore, and certain system settings (e.g. [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process#Boot_Configuration_Data)) are not affected by a restore.

System restore makes backups of:

- Registry hives
- Resources monitored via [Windows File Protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_File_Protection)
- The local user profile
- [COM+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#COM.2B) and [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) databases
- [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) metabase

It also keeps tracks of changes to files with [certain extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378870.aspx), in order to provide diff-based backups.

Since *most* malware persists on disk, with a registry key to make itself start on boot, a system restore should disable *most* malware. It most likely will not remove the malware from the disk, though. Other persistence mechanisms, such as code injection, will allow the malware to persist beyond a system restore.